# Error Saving Text Views in NSUserDefault

Tags: swift, textview

[image: how it looks like]

I have 6 textViews and one button to save the text wrote in them.
The problem is that the button just save until the forth TextView, fifth and sixth are not saved properly , they just copy the text in third and fourth textviews

Example

First text view - Correctly saved

Second text view - Correctly saved

Third text view - Correctly saved

Fourth text view - Correctly saved

Fifth text view - Its a copy of the text on third text view

Sixth text view - Its a copy of the text on fourth text view

Save button.

It seems all code are ok and all of the text views are linked successfully , but the last two textViews still fail.

My code here:

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

@IBOutlet weak var labelUno: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var labelDos: UILabel!


@IBOutlet weak var primerTextView: UITextView!

@IBOutlet weak var segundoTextView: UITextView!

@IBOutlet weak var tercerTextView: UITextView!

@IBOutlet weak var cuartoTextView: UITextView!

@IBOutlet weak var quintoTextView: UITextView!

@IBOutlet weak var sextoTextView: UITextView!






override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

      scrollView.contentSize.height = 2000

    labelUno.text = "¿Qué significa el éxito para ti? , ¿significa ser millonario , ser famoso , contribuir de alguna manera a ayudar a muchas personas, ser un buen padre o madre de familia, ser el mejor en tu profesión??"

    primerTextView.layer.borderWidth = 0.8
    primerTextView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    primerTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0


    segundoTextView.layer.borderWidth = 0.8
    segundoTextView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    segundoTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0

    tercerTextView.layer.borderWidth = 0.8
    tercerTextView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    tercerTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0

    cuartoTextView.layer.borderWidth = 0.8
    cuartoTextView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    cuartoTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0

    quintoTextView.layer.borderWidth = 0.8
    quintoTextView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    quintoTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0

    sextoTextView.layer.borderWidth = 0.8
    sextoTextView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    sextoTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0




    //Save Button
    let stringKey = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    segundoTextView.text = stringKey.stringForKey("key")
    primerTextView.text = stringKey.stringForKey("key2")
    tercerTextView.text = stringKey.stringForKey("key3")
    cuartoTextView.text = stringKey.stringForKey("key4")
    quintoTextView.text = stringKey.stringForKey("key5")
    sextoTextView.text = stringKey.stringForKey("key6")

    //Hide keyboard
    //Hide keyboard with touching anywhere
    var tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "DismissKeyboard")
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

}


func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()

    return true
}


@IBAction func saveButton(sender: AnyObject) {



    let myText = segundoTextView.text
    let myText2 = primerTextView.text
    let myText3 = tercerTextView.text
    let myText4 = cuartoTextView.text
    let myText5 = quintoTextView.text
    let myText6 = sextoTextView.text


    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myText, forKey: "key2")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myText2, forKey: "key")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myText3, forKey: "key3")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myText4, forKey: "key4")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myText3, forKey: "key5")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myText4, forKey: "key6")

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Guardado", message:"Tu texto se ha guardado", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))

    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)


}


//Hide keyboard with return button
func textView(textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextInRange range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if text == "\n"
    {
        primerTextView.resignFirstResponder()
        segundoTextView.resignFirstResponder()
        tercerTextView.resignFirstResponder()
        cuartoTextView.resignFirstResponder()
        quintoTextView.resignFirstResponder()
        sextoTextView.resignFirstResponder()


        return false
    }
    return true
}


//Hide keyboard with touching anywhere

func DismissKeyboard(){


    view.endEditing(true)

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that in this part:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myText, forKey: "key2")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myText2, forKey: "key")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myText3, forKey: "key3")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myText4, forKey: "key4")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myText3, forKey: "key5")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myText4, forKey: "key6")
```

It should be:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myText2, forKey: "key2")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myText, forKey: "key")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myText3, forKey: "key3")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myText4, forKey: "key4")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myText5, forKey: "key5")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(myText6, forKey: "key6")
```

It looks like a copy/paste error: put `myText5` and `myText6` instead of `myText3` and `myText4` in the two last lines.

Comment: :D :D :D now it's perfect!!
What a stupid mistake, thx so much Eric.

Comment: Don't worry, this kind of mistake happens to everybody... :) You're welcome!